# Apache AliasMatch shows content of directory?

Tags: apache, debian

What I'm trying to achieve is quite simple. I want Apache to use the content of `/home/user/www/bar/public` when users go to `www.example.com/foo/bar`. The `bar` part may change and I want Apache to be able to change the directory in consequence.

I tried to do this. And it works but it won't load my `index.php` file and actually shows the content of the directory...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    AliasMatch ^/foo/(.*)$ /home/user/www/$1/public
    <Directory /home/user/www/$1/public>
       AllowOverride all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

There isn't any .htaccess file and it doesn't need one because I managed to make it work with a subdomain :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName test.example.com
   DocumentRoot /home/user/www/test/public
   <Directory /home/user/www/test/public>
       AllowOverride all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm really stuck and any help would be great ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse the "$1" in the  section because that's  local to the AliasMatch.

You can simply use a wildcard if you are okay with applying the contents to every public dir under every subdir of /home/user/www